# FileNotFoundException in server project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I work on a indexing project which create a file dynamically for all words start with same  character and the name of that file is created based on first character of the words like:

> file "a" contains apple, adapt,air,...
>
> file "b" contains book, bad,bar,...

My project work correctly when I run through application but when I run it through server(tomcat) I got the following error for the given line of the code:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getFileName(word)));



INFO: Server startup in 2785 ms
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at DataLayer.FileRepository.getArrayListPosting(FileRepository.java:54)
```

I add the path to this word in the following code but I got the same error.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getFileName("C:\\code\\"+word)));
```

what should I do, where should I put this file in eclipse?
This is the image of my files in my project.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put file "word" in the main Eclipse project directory.  Don't worry about adding the path as per your 2nd try.

Comment: My second try does not work for me. and word is variable of string type.

Comment: Right.  So move the file to the main Eclipse project directory and just write the path as "word", without anything else (e.g. a path) prepended.  Also, use the variable as the file path and make sure the value stored in the variable is the name of the file.

Comment: I changed the location of that file to java resource part.Also I only wrote word but it did not work.what do you mean by eclipse project directory?

Comment: The main directory (outside the src/ folder).

Comment: Then don't use getFileName(word), just use word where you'd be using that.  Delete getFileName()

Answer (score 0):

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: C (The system cannot find the file specified)`

You probably forgot the `:` in the path, and accidently made it `C\\File` which is looking for a directory named `C`, which doesnt exist.

Comment: colon appears in the path OP posted though.

Comment: what do you mean La-comadreja

Comment: What I mean is your last post "No I did not forget."

Comment: sorry that comment was the answer of the DirkyJerky not you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that calling function which create the name of the project as argument of fileReader.The solution is :

```
String str= path+getFileName(word);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

Any of these two solutions

1________
put the "word" file in the eclipse project directory. i.e the folder that contains the eclipse.exe application file

2_______
File file=new File("theFileFullPath");
According to your program, do it this way => File file= new File("C:\code\"+word)));

then::

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file.getAbsolutePath()));